# MkDir sFolderPath

Tags: excel, vba, mkdir

I have been using the code for many different workbooks but for some reason I'm getting an error 37 whenever I try to run it in a new workbook project.

```
Public Sub SaveAsA1()
Range("C9").Value = Application.UserName

Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("C8")
    If IsEmpty(rRng.Value) Then

        MsgBox ("Cell (C8) is empty. Please scan in the correct work order number into (C8)")
        End
    Else
    End If

Dim Result As Integer
Result = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If Result = vbYes Then
MsgBox "\\us.\TEST_DATA\MODULE\" & "WO_" & Range("C8")
Else
End
End If
 
'Variable declaration
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    
    'Define Folder Path
    sFolderPath = "Now saving to \\us.\TEST_DATA\MODULE\" & "WO_" & Range("C8")
    
    'Create FSO Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'Check Specified Folder exists or not
    If oFSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        'If Folder is available
    Else
    
    'If folder is not available
    MkDir sFolderPath '<-------------Run time error 76
     End If
```

I expect to create a new folder if one does not already exist. I removed the MkDir code, and it worked but now I don't have an IF protocol.

Comment: Is the `Now saving to ` part of `sFolderPath` for our benefit, or are you actually trying to create a folder called that?

Comment: I believe the `Now saving to` should be in the messagebox above, not the actual string path.

Comment: What kind of error is Error 37? Please share its description.

Comment: Typo should say error 76

Comment: Fixed!!! Now saving to should be in the messagebox above was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!! Now saving to should be in the messagebox above was the issue.